# Subtitile editor[.srt to .ssa]

Tags: java, swing, subtitle

I have been working on a subtitling system on java.
the normal .srt file can be saved and the subtitles are seen fine.
i want the subtitles to have different properties like diff font/color/size all these properties are not encoded in a normal .srt, the file has to be saved as .ssa(substation alpha) with extra fields like [v4+ style] and events..
i want to know that are there any libraries which i can use to export directly to .ssa or do i have to write a method which includes the [v4+ style]

Thank you.

Comment: I used to write it manually. It wouldn't be so complex, just follow its format.

Answer (score 1):

[jubler](http://www.jubler.org/features/index.php) is an open source library that seems to support substation alpha format.